# traverse firebase list (previous and next sibling)

Tags: angularjs, firebase

Is it possible to get the next child in a firebase list? I'm using the 'push()' functionality for lists. When I remove one item from the list I want to select the adjacent element so that there is always an item selected. But there is no way to get the sibling item.

Comment: You can use the .limit() query applied to a Firebase reference (which pass in to AngularFire) to fetch a fixed number of children at a time (including siblings). Whenever you run out of siblings, you can do another fetch for the next batch of 10 (say), with a combination of startAt().limit(10). See queries: https://www.firebase.com/docs/queries.html

Comment: Thanks Anant, but I want to traverse the query I just made. So there's a callback with a snapshot of, say, 10 children. I want to move through that list and sort them.

Comment: You can call snapshot.forEach() to traverse it in order of priority.